# Where is the app.dll.config

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, assemblies, app-config

I have a C# Class Library (dll; .net 4.0). I'll call it "mytestlib". I added a Settings.setting to it which also adds a app.config file to the project. It has a couple of application scope properties in it and also some user scope properties.

During debug I can see the "mytestlib.dll.config" file in the bin\Debug folder where I expect it to be. However, when I install the library using an MSI installer I do not find the "mytestlib.dll.config" anywhere on the system! Where does Microsoft put the app.dll.config?? I am starting to suspect it is actually embedded in the dll (I hope that is not the case).

I do know it is there somewhere because the exe application that uses this dll does successfully pull settings from the "mytestlib.dll.config" file. The problem I do not know where the file is.

btw, I am able to find the user.config.

Please help and thank you in advance!

Note: I can do this same thing with a Windows Form applcation (exe) and then install that using an MSI installer and I find the app.exe.config side by side with the .exe as I would expect. Why does the app.dll.config not work the same way?

Comment: The actual config file is associated with the .exe, not the .dll. DLL's do not have their own .config file.  Could be that the compiler generates the .dll.config for your reference (never tried that with a dll), but appropriate sections would have to be copied to the app.config for the .exe.

Comment: it might need to be included with your installer.

Comment: where does the MSI install the DLL?

Comment: I have one project that puts the dll in the same folder as the exe. But I have another project where the dll goes into the GAC. I do not find the app.dll.config for either one though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation there is no configuration file model for class libraries. The app/user settings defined in the libarary will actually use the app/user.config of the exe that is referecing the library. Therefore there is no app.dll.config (the settings go in the app.exe.config of the app referenceing the dll).

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things:

1 - You should put consider putting relevant config entries in the launching *.exe.config.  These will be picked up by the DLL accordingly.

2 - Your installer probably wouldn`t know about the conifg file unless you specifically told it to anyway.

3 - The DLL config file was created for use in test projects and other scenarios, not necessarily for runtime, though you could probably deploy it and use it at runtime if you so wished.

Comment: only problem is the exe that uses our dll is owned by another party.

Comment: @cchampion Can you clarify what you mean by owned?  Why does it impede adding your entries to the config file?

Comment: By owned I mean it is another companys application and I have no access to the source code.

Comment: @cchampion You don`t need access to their source code to change the exe.config file at runtime.